# function with one argument that search for word and then replace something on that line

Tags: vimscript

I want to create a custom function that:

- Take 1 argument
- Search for a word
- On that line do a movement like f@
- change till " (ct") with the argument I provided

Example:

Library "sharedLibrary@xyz"

command zyv should produce

Library "sharedLibrary@zyv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comfortable with ex-commands, you can use something like this in your function

```
function MyFn(replacement) abort
  /word
  substitute/@\zs.\{-}\ze"/\=a:replacement/
endfunction
```

We search for `word`, then substitute everything between `@` and the first `"` (hence non-greedy matching with `\{-}`) with the argument `a:replacement`.

With functions/`:normal!`, it would be something like

```
call search('word')
execute printf('normal! f@ct"%s', a:replacement)
```

Which I think is a bit harder to read.

---

Another alternative would be to use a macro: I won't save/restore it, but that's not hard to add.

```
let @q = '/word<C-v><CR>f@ct"'.a:replacement.'<C-v><esc>'
@q
```

But I don't know of a good way to avoid embedding the control characters literally (you have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and the corresponding key (enter, escape) inside the string).

Comment: Nice it works and then I did this mapping:
:nnoremap <buffer> <leader> can :call MyFn(input('Param: '))<CR>